# SSH/SCP hanging

Tags: linux, ssh, freeze, scp

I have two computers connected through an ssh connection. They are placed few miles away but the Internet connections is quite bad.

When I try to exchange a bit more data, the ssh console just hangs. I'm talking about typing "ps" or "dmesg"...

If I try to upload something with scp it stalls at the beginning, without transfering 1 byte. Of course, this is not a problem while on the LAN.

I don't know what I could do to investigate further. What do you suggest?

Comment: Do protocols other than SSH work?

Comment: A plain TCP connection from my C++ application isn't reliable too. Sometimes packets are no longer received and I have to close and reopen the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a second network interface enabled and configured to the same subnet. Unfortunately, I wasn't aware of that. Once discovered I tried several times to duplicate the situation and I confirm the behavior.

With two LAN interfaces configured to the same network (different IP, same subnet and gateway) both don't work well. You have to move one of them to another subnet.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Mosh](https://mosh.mit.edu/). In the authors' words:

> Remote terminal application that allows roaming, supports intermittent connectivity, and provides intelligent local echo and line editing of user keystrokes.
>
> Mosh is a replacement for SSH. It's more robust and responsive, especially over Wi-Fi, cellular, and long-distance links.
>
> **Change IP. Stay connected.**
>
> Mosh automatically roams as you move between Internet connections. Use Wi-Fi on the train, Ethernet in a hotel, and LTE on a beach: you'll stay logged in. Most network programs lose their connections after roaming, including SSH and Web apps like Gmail. Mosh is different.

I especially like it because it fixes problems in `ssh`, like the Unicode bug, and the lack of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. But it also handles network lag much better.

It exists for all OSes, but in Windows you will need to have Cygwin installed.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not going to use Mosh in this case, but you pointed me to a very interesting tool which I didn't know. Thanks.